# Homebrew disables curl config file. How do I set no_proxy to fetch packages with no proxy?

Tags: curl, homebrew

I've set my .bashrc with the line:

```
export {no_proxy,NO_PROXY}=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

and test that curl works with no_proxy:

```
/usr/bin/curl https://mirrorservice.org/pub/OpenBSD/LibreSSL/libressl-2.8.2.tar.gz --connect-timeout 5
```

This works.

Upgrading a package using `curl` to fetch the binaries causes an error:

```
==> Upgrading libressl

Downloading https://mirrorservice.org/pub/OpenBSD/LibreSSL/libressl-2.8.2.tar.gz
/usr/bin/curl -q --show-error https://mirrorservice.org/pub/OpenBSD/LibreSSL/libressl-2.8.2.tar.gz --connect-timeout 5
```

The error is:

```
 Could not resolve proxy: proxy.[MY_PROXY_NAME]
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
```

Because curl includes a -q command:

```
   -q, --disable
          If  used  as the first parameter on the command line, the curlrc
          config file will not be read and used.
```

I tried the command:

```
$ no_proxy=localhost brew upgrade -verbose
```

But that still doesn't work. How do I skip Homebrew from bypassing curlrc.